# Odoo Email resend to the sender on exception

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, xml, odoo, odoo-12

In the invoice module, whenever there is failed to send the email through send_and_print_action, its showing the red mail icon in the chatter by default. But in addition, to that, I want to resend the 'Failed Message' email to the sender about the exception as well. Not sure, where to get started. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what if the mail was unable to send because of outgoing mail server, even the exception mail will also fail.

Comment: I want to resend the email back to the sender if the mail was not sent because of an invalid email